# Cохранить расчеты с кнопки и отобразить все найденные значения на графике

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Первая кнопка отвечает за переход во второй активити, а вот значения второй кнопки надо запомнить: сохранить в arraylist или массив. Что угодно, лишь бы график можно было построить по этим точкам

```
public void onClick(View p) {
    switch (p.getId()) {
        case R.id.perehod:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Grafic.class);

            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    {
        TextView resu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        int res = apple * 70 + mandarin * 53 + patato * 133 + rise * 65 + kotlet * 216 + gulash * 204 + rassolnik * 107 + borsh * 157;
        resu.setText(Integer.toString(res));
    }
}
```

Второй активити, где находится график. НЕОБХОДИМО, чтобы точки были построены по результатам  ***res***

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grafic);


    GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(0,0),
            new DataPoint(1,1),
            new DataPoint(5,5)

    });
    graph.addSeries(series);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кладите нужные данные в intent в первой активности:

```
intent.putExtra("KEY", res);
```

Затем во второй активности получайте эти данные:

```
int res = (int) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("KEY");
```

Массив или лист аналогично передается.

Comment: Хотелось бы все в массив занести, но тогда страница вылетает
int[] res = (int[]) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("kkal");
        GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
                new DataPoint(0, res[0]),
                new DataPoint(1, res[1]),
                new DataPoint(2, res[2]),
 Если все без массива делать, то точек нет